# Oracle11g localhost: 1158/em cannot connect

Tags: localhost, postgresql, oracle-11g

In my Windows 7 professional edition, I installed Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 which is downloaded from Oracle.com. The SID is 'orcl', username is 'system'.

When I attempt connect to Database Control - orcl ( localhost:1158/em ) it works fine the first time but after restarting the Windows localhost:1158/em does not connect.

The browser says "temporarily unavailable".

After Oracle installation I also installed PostgreSQL 9.2, phpPgAdmin 5.1 on my WAMP server 2.0.

Note: I disabled Windows Firewall, and disabled my antivirus.

Comment: Wow, you've left out pretty much every useful detail. What OS are you on? Version? How'd you install Oracle? How'd you install PostgreSQL and from where? What's in the Oracle logs? etc etc etc. Right now, someone would require some serious psychic powers to answer usefully unless they'd already seen this issue happen themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There are following step to start the dbconsole. Step one first check your database is up and running.

How will you check it? On the linux prompt type the following command.

```
$ ps -ef|grep oracle
```

If it is not showing any thing then connect with Sql, with sysdba

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
sql>select name from v$database;
```

It will show you the database name. Then shutdown the database...

```
sql>shut immediate;

sql>start nomount;

sql>alter database mount;

sql>alter database open;

sql>exit
```

On linux prompt check the listener is up and running or not. The command to check for the listener is as follows

```
$ lsnrctl status
```

If it is not up and running then start your listener first. Commmand to start the listener is as follows

```
$ lsnrctl start
```

After that you start the emctl with following command

```
$ emctl start dbconsole
```

It will start your enterprise manager. Now click on the link or copy paste link into the browser. If you have missing setting into browser, then check the setting of it.

Comment: He's using windows tho, locally.